# Why max (max(a,b), c) is error

Tags: c++

Reference: code snippet from C++ Template: The Complete Guide

```
// maximum of two values of any type (call-by-reference) 
template <typename T> 
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b) 
{ 
    return a < b ? b : a; 
} 

// maximum of two C-strings (call-by-value) 
inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b) 
{ 
    return std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a; 
} 

// maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference) 
template <typename T> 
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c) 
{ 
    return max (max(a,b), c); // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value 
} 

int main () 
{ 
    ::max(7, 42, 68); // OK 

    const char* s1 = "frederic"; 
    const char* s2 = "anica"; 
    const char* s3 = "lucas"; 
    ::max(s1, s2, s3); // ERROR 

}
```

Stated issues for above code:

> The problem is that if you call max() for three C-strings, the
>   statement
>
> return max (max(a,b), c);  becomes an error. This is because for
>   C-strings, max(a,b) creates a new, temporary local value that may be
>   returned by the function by reference.

Question> I still don't understand the points above. Why

> "you can't use the three-argument version to compute the maximum of
>   three C-strings"?

// Update

```
const int* fReturnValue(const int *i)
{
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    const int* i4= fReturnValue(&i);

    cout << &i << endl;
    cout << i4 << endl;
}
```

Observation: both lines return the same address.
So I assume that in function fReturnValue, the function returns by value but it doesn't hurt b/c it is a pointer address. In other words, the return address is still valid.

Is that true?

Comment: as far as i know, strcmp is not part of std namespace...

Comment: @thang: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: @thang: `cstring` I guess? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: cstring is an include file?  which c++ standard?

Comment: potential dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339601/warning-returning-reference-to-temporary, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667161/c-returning-reference-to-temporary, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298809/returning-a-reference-to-temporary

Comment: @thang: `cstring` is an include file, sure, any _C++_ standard. All types and functions inherited from the _C_ standard library live both at the global namespace as well as the `std` namespace.

Comment: never used that before, let me try it...

Comment: wow, it worked... cool.  did not know that.  i always used the c version in string.h

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the *C-string* flavor of `max` returns by value, not so much that it takes its arguments by value. The generic 3-way `max` function is declared to return a reference but the *C-string* `max` returns a value, which would then result in returning a reference to a temporary that will be dead before you can access it.

**Update**: The new code you added is not equivalent to your original problem. This would:

```
const int*& fReturnValue(const int *i)
{
    return i;
}
```

Note that `fReturnValue` returns a reference to the local variable `i`, whose lifetime ends by the time the function returns. So the function returns a reference to an invalid object. Try to compile your code with that change, you should get a warning from pretty much every compiler.

Comment: Why it returns by value? It returns address by value. what that is a problem? `inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b) ` returns the address of the pass-in variable.

Comment: @q0987: It returns by value because its declared to do so. The generic 3-way `max` will then try to return a reference to that temporary pointer holding the address, said temporary pointer will be dead by the time `max` returns (the pointer, not the address in it).

Comment: So if the function returns pointer by reference, then what makes any difference. I mean what the pointer stores then?

Comment: @q0987: The problem is that it returns a reference to a pointer that no longer exist. In fact it is no different than `int*& f(){ int* ptr = 0; return ptr; }`

Comment: May you check my update? I have illustrated an example that mimics the same thing about max function. Even after the function returns, the address is still valid.

Comment: @q0987: Change it to this `const int*& fReturnValue(const int *i){ return i; }` and you'll get the same behavior than with your original code, that of returning a reference to a temporary pointer that is already dead. Note that I've mentioned all times now that the problem is with returning a reference to an invalid pointer to an address. There is no problem with the address, it will still be valid, the reference to the temporary pointer holding that address well... that's another story... Try it out, your compiler should be issuing a _"Returning reference to temporary" warning.

Comment: thank you so much for your great helps. Now I think I get your idea. Basically, the variable `i` in `fReturnValue` is a local variable and it is wrong to return a reference to a local variable!