# How pointer pointee value returned without dereferencing pointer?

Tags: c++

When I reading *C++ Templates The Complete Guide (David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis)* I confused at following example

This example is copied from titled *overloading function templates*, but my question is not related to overloading nor template.

How s1, s2 and s3 pointers returned as value from max function. s1 , s2 and s3 contains address of char array but how these address converted to value without dereferencing that pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

// maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
return max (max(a,b), c); // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
}

int main ()
{
const char* s1 = "frederic";
const char* s2 = "anica";
const char* s3 = "lucas";
::max(s1, s2, s3); // ERROR
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this example is trying to demonstrate. Can you give some context? Is `max` `std::max`?

Comment: This example is overloading function templates, but my question is not related to overloading nor template.

Comment: It's not comparing the strings they point to, it's comparing the pointers themselves by the memory addresses they point to.

Comment: Also, T const& a means a const reference of a const char*. There is no dereferencing here.

Comment: Your example code fails to compile because you're calling a 2-argument `max` function which is not defined.

Comment: @Simple thank you, thats answer for my question. is it compare memory address and returns value of it pointed to?

Comment: @Simple paramaters are values to compare not memory address! > http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/

Comment: @Tek the value of a pointer is the memory address it points to.

Comment: @Simple, can you say what this returns as parameter : **T const& a**  . is it memory address or "frederic" ?

Comment: @Tek in `::max(s1, s2, s3)` then `T` is `const char*` which means the whole type is `const char* const&`. This means you are comparing the addresses that the pointers are pointing at.

Comment: @Simple, That is really helpful comment.You saved tens of hours. I assumed T is only `char`. Sorry i am very new to c++ . Thank you very much. If you open answer i will accept

Comment: @Eric Fortin also thank you really helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is comparing the addresses that the pointers point to, not the values of the objects the pointers are pointing at.

In the example of `::max(s1, s2, s3)` the type `T` is `const char*` which means the whole type is `const char* const&`, and using comparison operators like `<` and `>` (which `max` uses under-the-hood) compare which pointer is "pointing at a greater address".

Answer (score 1):

> but how these address converted to value without dereferencing that
>   pointers

If I understand what you mean by "converted to value". They aren't. The function is simply comparing the values of the pointers, i.e. the addresses that they store, which is completely unrelated to the actual contents of the strings at those addresses. Assuming here that the 2 argument `max` is actually `std::max`.

If it is not `std::max`, then perhaps they are simply invoking an unspecified function for the purposes of demonstration. And maybe that unspecified function *does* dereference the pointers. We can't see it, so we don't know. The only thing you've shown is a 3 argument version.

On a second look, it is clear in fact that they are not using `std::max`, or at least they are not assuming the use of `std::max`.

```
return max (max(a,b), c); // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
```

Notice the "if" in the comment. `std::max` doesn't use call-by-value, so there is no point in that comment if we are assuming `std::max`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this post: [Why max (max(a,b), c) is error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14989564/2701518)? I think it's about the same example. Apparently the string version of `max` does the dereferncing internally.

Comment: Yes i favorited that post before.

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting this as an answer.

Comment: @Wyzard I just wanted to make a comment, but my reputation didn't allow me to do so. I think I'm not allowed to flag neither.